# get the average from two distinct columns joining other tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table in mySQL with sample data:

> **Table1**:

```
id    type    locid    month    qty
1     car1      1      JAN       2
2     car1      1      FEB       1
3     car1      2      JAN       3
4     car1      2      MAR       2
5     car2      1      FEB       2
6     car2      1      MAY       5
```

> **Table2**:

```
id    location
1        CA
2        NY
```

I have difficulty in getting the average of the quantity from this distinct two columns which is the type and the location. Would it be possible to compute the average with in the past 3 months only?

Here is the result I would like to accomplish:

```
type      CA_AVE      NY_AVE
-----------------------------
car1        1.5         2.5
car2        2  <-- assumed the current month is MARCH so the qty for MAY should 
                   not be included to get the average
```

Comment: I think it's better to result in rows, not columns (what if you have 200 locations, not just 2?). Does this matters? Also, not clear what is 'last 3 month'. You have no `APR` value. So, will it be 0 for April? Or will it be `MAY`, `MAR`, `FEB`?

Comment: I was thinking of it as rows considering the number of locations that will be added. The past 3 months in the format of MAY, MAR, JAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your answer.
but you should conside now month is aug not march b/c i used now().
okey. so change your table data accordingly and check the result.

```
select AVG( loc) as loc,AVG(qty) as qty from tbl1  where month NOT IN (concat(UCASE(DATE_FORMAT(date_add(now(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH),'%b')),',',
         UCASE(DATE_FORMAT(date_add(now(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH),'%b')),',',
         UCASE(DATE_FORMAT(date_add(now(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH),'%b')))) group by type
```

For DEMO Click here:-http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a15e/15

Comment: I change my table accordingly to the desired format and got the result. thanks